# Is there a dot product of sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, operator-theory

<strike>Let's say I have sets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{x,y,z\}$, I'd like the output to be $\{1x, 2y, 3z\}$, is there such an operation?</strike>

Let's say I have sets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{x,y,z\}$, I'd like the output to be $\{1x,1y,1z,2x,2y,2z,3x,3y,3z\}$, is there such an operation?

The specific case I'm trying to deal with is a set of tuples $\{(s_1, c_1), (s_2, c_2), ...\}$ where $s_i$ is a set, and $c_i$ is a constant. Given 2 of such sets, I'd like to find an operation that allows me to do the following:

$$A \,(something) \, B = \{ \;(s_i \cap s_j, c_i * c_j) \; | \;(s_i, c_i) \in A, (s_j, c_j) \in B \; \}$$

Thanks!

Comment: You can only do such things with tuples - remember that $\{1,2,3\}=\{3,2,1\}$, so you can't use the order of the elements on an operation on the sets.

Comment: Sets are unordered, so there is no way to know which elements of the first set should be paired up with which elements of the second set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no dot product of sets.

Your first example is problematic, because

$$\{1,2,3\} = \{2,1,3\}$$

so the product could equally be $\{2x, y, 3z\}$. So what you are describing is **not well defined**

Comment: What if the output is $\{1x, 1y, 1z, 2x, 2y, 2z, 3x, 3y, 3z\}$, now is there an operator?

Comment: @esjd What you now described is almost, but not quite, the cartesian product. I don't know of any operator that does this, however. You can define your own, of course.